# Shortcode for a Series of Elevating Image Files, Excluding a Range?

Tags: php, shortcode

I'm not sure if shortcodes have the capability of doing this and could not figure out how to do it on my own. Is this even possible?

I have a series of images in several folders outside of WP. They are screencaps of different TV episodes, including the commercials. However, I don't want the commercials' screencaps showing. Would it be possible to make a shortcode that works like this?:

```
[episode num="1" images="1-100, 110-200, 230-300" title="Pilot"]
```

Which would output the HTML as like `<img src="/path/to/episodes/1/1.jpg" alt="Pilot" title="Pilot">` for every file from 1 through 100, then for every file from 110 to 200, etc.? The confusing thing here for me is that I can't figure out how to program it to use a range of numbers and exclude others.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you'll just have to parse the `images` parameter (by using `explode`, for example). Have you been able to implement this shortcode for, say, displaying just a single image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code snippet:

```
/**
 * Shortcode for a series of elevating image files, excluding a range
 *
 * @link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/151408/26350
 */

add_shortcode( 'episode', 'episode_shortcode' );

function episode_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = '' )
{
    //-----------------------
    // Settings:
    //
    $path   = '/path/to/files';
    $ext    = 'jpg';
    //-----------------------

    // Shortcode input:
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array( 'num' => 0, 'title' => '', 'images' => '' ), 
        $atts, 
        'episode_shortcode' 
    );

    // Sanitize input:
    $images = esc_attr( $atts['images'] );
    $title  = esc_attr( $atts['title'] );
    $num    = (int) $atts['num'];

    // Init:
    $html   = '';    
    $ranges = explode( ',', $images );

    // Loop over input ranges:    
    foreach( $ranges as $range )
    {
        $rng = explode( '-', $range );

        if( count( $rng ) == 2 )
        {
            $from = (int) trim( $rng[0] );
            $to   = (int) trim( $rng[1] );

            foreach( range( $from, $to ) as $i )
            {
                 $html .= sprintf( '<img src="%s/%d/%s.%s" alt="%s"/>', 
                     $path,
                     $num,
                     $i, 
                     $ext,
                     $title 
                 );
            }
        }
    } 

    return $html;
}
```

It might be faster for a very large loop to skip `sprintf()`, I use it here for better readability.